# Assign color based on value of a defined distribution and limited range in R

Tags: r, colors

I'm plotting segments with ggplot and I want to color the segments depending on an associated value, but comparing values coming from different sources. The original data frame has more than 10000 values per experiment, but for plotting only few are subset (~30-50).

So far I have used an strategy using colorRampPallete:

```
col <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "white", "red"))
```

Then generate colors based on each value of every experiment, from the whole range having as a base the red and blue gradient (median in all is ~0)

```
dat_original$colvalue1 <- col(10)[as.numeric(cut(dat_original$value1, breaks=10))]
dat_original$colvalue2 <- col(10)[as.numeric(cut(dat_original$value2, breaks=10))]
```

After subsetting, I use the assigned color to color the segment. But I want to compare values from different experiments, so when I generate the colors, as the distributions are different (some have a wider range) the colors cannot be compared (eg similar negative value has a whiter color in one compared to other experiment)

As I want to compare segments/values from different experiments, and the range can differ I want to assign the values based on a limited distribution, ie. normal distribution / range, e.g. -5,5 mean=0 and sd=1, so the colors intensity can be compared. More specifically, if the value in one is -1.2 and in the second is -2 the latter should be more blue, but if one is -1.2 and the other -1.25 the difference should be almost non-existing.

A dummy data frame of how the subset looks like

```
ident <- c("ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "DEF", "DEF", "GHF", "GHF", "GHF")
a3 <- c(10, 15, 20, 30, 45, 60, 80, 90)
a4 <- c(14, 19, 28, 40, 55, 75, 85, 100)
value1 <- c(-3.7,-1.8,-1.5, 2,0.5, -0.5,-0.9, -1.5)
value2 <- c(-2.2,-3.8,-4, 1.2,1.5, -0.8,-1.9, -0.5)
#
dat <- data.frame(ident, a1, a2, a3, a4, value1, value2)
#Plot, I'm using after assigning the colors to colvalue1 or 2
ggplot(dat) +
geom_segment(aes(x=a3, xend=a4, y=as.numeric(ident), yend=as.numeric(ident)), size=4, 
color=dat$colvalue1) +
geom_segment(aes(x=a3, xend=a4, y=as.numeric(ident)+0.2, yend=as.numeric(ident)+0.2),
 size=4, , color=dat$colvalue1)
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Not sure this is the right answer, but what about `ggplot(dat) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=a3, xend=a4, y=as.numeric(ident), yend=as.numeric(ident),color=value1), size=4) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=a3, xend=a4, y=as.numeric(ident)+0.2, yend=as.numeric(ident)+0.2,color=value2),size=4)` ? That produces a continuous color_scale and the scale is unique (ie. not need to worry about disparities between datasets).

Comment: Thank you very much, this seems to be a really good option as it color it with a unique scale, and produces what I'm looking for. I have combined it with `scale_color_gradient2` to have the colors from blue to red passing by white, with limits -5 to 5, though I don't know if that's the way to go.

Comment: IMO, limits are not necessary, since ggplot will adjust and pick the min and max values as the limit to maximize contrast. They are only useful if you have outliers. You may want to change the plot background with this gradient in order to distinguish the white segments `+ theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill="grey"))`

Comment: You are right. In my case I wanted to use it because of what you mentioned the presence of some outliers, I also modified the background as well. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map a numeric vector to color and use `scale_color_gradient()`

```
ggplot(dat) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x=a3, xend=a4, y=as.numeric(ident), yend=as.numeric(ident),color=value1), size=4) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x=a3, xend=a4, y=as.numeric(ident)+0.2, yend=as.numeric(ident)+0.2,color=value2),size=4) +
  scale_color_gradient2(low="blue",high="red")+
  theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill="grey"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I used a similar approach, but with `scale_color_gradient2` as in the comment, as it gave more options for my purpose. But this achieves it as well